# Register assignment for outer loops

Tags: compiler-construction, code-generation, register-allocation

I was going through the red dragon book and in the section **Register Assignment for Outer Loops**, I came across the following statement which is not quite clear to me.

> If an outer loop `L1` contains an inner loop `L2`, the names allocated registers in `L2` need not be allocated registers in `L1 - L2`

What do they want to say? Are they talking about variables that are used in both `L1` and `L2` and these names are allocated registers in `L2`. I do not quite get the situation meant in the text.

Can anyone explain to me a possible example?

[image: Block Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common optimisation is to keep variables used in a loop in registers for the duration of the loop. That can make a huge difference in tight loops because it avoids use of memory.

As with any optimisation of this form, the register will need to be initialised with the value of the variable before the loop starts, which might mean reading it from memory. And  if the variable is modified during the loop and still in use afterwards, it may be necessary to save it back to its memory location. Still, that's at most one memory read and one write, as opposed to reading and writing the variable's value in every iteration.

The decision of which variables to optimise in this way is important. And here arises the possibility that a variable is used in an inner loop but not in the enclosing outer loop. In this case, it's possible that there are more beneficial uses of registers in the outer loop.

So it is not necessary that a register reserved for an optimised variable in an inner loop will be also reserved in a containing loop. It might even be worthwhile to save the value of the register before starting the inner loop and restore it on inner loop exit. All of that depends on the optimiser's best guess of loop repetition counts, the number of optimisation use sites of the variable, and of course the number of registers available.

Comment: `So it is not a given that a register reserved for an optimised variable in an inner loop will be also reserved in a containing loop.` did not get it @rici

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: is English the problem? "Not a given" means that it is not necessarily the case.

Comment: Yes I cannot understand the English. Sorry for that... :(

Comment: now I get it. What the authors wanted to say or what the quoted text in my question meant, after reading your explanation and after you explained the English to me. Thanks a lot. I see I am getting stuck at many places of this book, simply because I cannot understand or correlate the meaning of sentences in the text to the context. :(